# When a loadbalancer sits between MQ and app, loadbalancer consumes the messages?

Tags: java, activemq-classic, load-balancing

When a loadbalancer sits between MQ and same apps on two servers, it is loadbalancer who is the listener and consumes the mesaage and passes it to one of the apps?

Answer (score 1):

In general, a loadbalancer is just a network appliance and therefore should only be passing through network traffic.  It shouldn't act as an application component.